# Generate bar-chart using jFreechart with guava lib

Tags: java, jfreechart, guava

Please Please assist.

I am using guava lib from google to generate X-Y Line chart with jFreeChart. I am able to generate simple X-Y Line chart. However i am not able to generate bar-char with it.

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: What did you try? What problems did you face?

Answer (score 8):

From a tutorial guide, which I believe is located here: [pdf](http://dvillela.servehttp.com:4000/apostilas/jfreechart_tutorial.pdf)

Bar Chart Example

Suppose that we want to construct a bar graph which compares the profits taken in
by the following salesmen: Jane, Tom, Jill, John, Fred.

```
public class BarChartExample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Create a simple Bar chart
 DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
  dataset.setValue(6, "Profit", "Jane");
  dataset.setValue(7, "Profit", "Tom");
  dataset.setValue(8, "Profit", "Jill");
  dataset.setValue(5, "Profit", "John");
  dataset.setValue(12, "Profit", "Fred");
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Comparison between Salesman",
  "Salesman", "Profit", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
   false, true, false);
try {
     ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("C:\\chart.jpg"), chart, 500, 300);
} catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
}}}
```

[image]

Explanation:

To define a data set for a bar graph use an object of class

```
DefaultCategoryDataset.
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
```

Values can be added to the data set using the setValue() method.

```
dataset.setValue(6, “Profit”, “Jane”);
```

The first argument specifies the level of profit achieved by Jane. The second argument specifies
what will appear in the legend for the meaning of a bar.
To generate a bar graph object of class JFreeChart, the method createBarChart() of
ChartFactory is used. It takes the same set of arguments as that required by
createXYLineChart(). The 1st argument denotes the title of the graph, the second
the label for the x-axis, the third the label for the y-axis.

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Comparison between Salesman",
"Salesman", "Profit", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
```

Modification: As was the case with pie charts, it is possible to display the bars in 3D using the createBarChart3D() method.

Modification:

One thing that might be worthwhile is to adjust the appearance of the graph (e.g. colour).

```
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.yellow); // Set the background colour of the chart
chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.blue); // Adjust the colour of the title
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); // Get the Plot object for a bar graph
p.setBackgroundPaint(Color.black); // Modify the plot background
p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red); // Modify the colour of the plot gridlines
```

Hopefully you can rework it to fit your needs,

Good Luck!